# Can Bluemix single sign on service be applied to Bluemix Docker scalable groups?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

When I try to connect SSO service, I only see the Cloudfoundry apps, and not the Docker Liberty containers. Is there a way this SSO service can be used for authenticating on containers?

I have also asked this question at [Bluemix Forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/320055/can-bluemix-single-sign-on-service-be-applied-to-t/)

Comment: I have been trying to use the bridge CF container. Will update with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not use the SSO service with containers.  Sorry for the inconvenience.